# Where does my error message show up with React Forms?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

If I write this in React:

```
  <input
    type="text"
    style={{ width: "50px" }}
    required
    placeholder="###"
    pattern="\d{3}"
  />
```

`

And I try to submit the form while I don't follow the 3 digit pattern, a little tab comes down with the words "Please follow requested format".

If I use these two imports:
`import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"; import { ErrorMessage } from "@hookform/error-message";`

And then try this:

`<input {...register("first", { required: true, pattern: { value: /\d{3}/, message: "kljlk" } })} />`

It stops the form from getting submitted if I did not follow the pattern, but where does the "message" go?  I don't see the same little tab the above code generates.

Answer (score 0):

You can display error messages using the errors object provided by react-hook-form. This object contains any errors that occurred during validation, and you can reference it to display the error message wherever you like in your component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

function MyForm() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input
        {...register('first', {
          required: 'This field is required',
          pattern: {
            value: /\d{3}/,
            message: 'Please enter exactly 3 digits'
          }
        })}
      />
      {/* Display error message */}
      {errors.first && <p>{errors.first.message}</p>}

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

export default MyForm;
```

Comment: Just a tip, always use a double negative when doing conditional rendering, this will ensure that the value is boolean e.g.: `!!errors.first &&`. See more here: https://dev.to/maafaishal/avoid-operator-for-conditional-rendering-in-react-2de

Comment: Thank you bbut ow the program doesn't seem to be paying attention to validation at all, unfortunately.

Comment: It will print out the error when you try to submit the form, not before.
Please accept the answer if it answered your question `where does the "message" go?`